# Common Berthing Mechanism Dimensions

Tags: iss, cbm

I've found detailed information on the International Docking Standard, enough to start work on a detailed CAD of the mechanism.

(http://www.internationaldockingstandard.com/download/IDSS_IDD_Revision_E_TAGGED.pdf)

I haven't been able to find the same info for the two sides of the Common Berthing Mechanism.  NASA has some 3d models, but I'd rather not rely on someone else's reading of a document.

Thanks

Comment: Two possibilities for someone who wants to take the time to write up an answer -- https://prod.nais.nasa.gov/eps/eps_data/155430-OTHER-001-009.pdf  && https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19920015843.pdf both seem to include detailed descriptions.

Comment: Saiboogu, excellent resources.  Thank you!  However far that gets me, I'll follow up with a grabcad file.