# CBM dimensions for docking rings, auxillary umbilicals, and passage are in both active and passive sides

Tags: iss, dimensions, cbm

I am trying to 3D print some models for imagined and actual space craft. I was wondering if anyone was aware of technical drawings or other documents that give shapes and dimensions of the elements of the [Common Berthing Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Berthing_Mechanism). I am looking for information specific enough to render a reasonably accurate model. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26067/6944 but it does not have an answer.